# Wrap fetch API in class method React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, oop, react-native

In a bid to make my React Native code more structured, in my latest project, I decided to create a class that holds all fetch requests. The structure of the class is seen below:

```
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';

// const API_URL = 'http://localhost:5500';
const API_URL = 'https://trail-api.herokuapp.com';

export default class Backend {
  static logIn(username, password){
    fetch(`${API_URL}/users/login`, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json'
      },
      body: {
        username: username,
        password: password
      }
    });
  }
  static signUp(firstname, lastname, username, email, password){
    fetch(`${API_URL}/users/register`, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json'
      },
      body: {
        firstname: firstname,
        lastname: lastname,
        username: username,
        email: email,
        password: password,
        confirmpassword: password
      }
    });
  }
  static getUser(){
    AsyncStorage.getItem('@Trail:user');
  }
  static getFeed(username){
    fetch(`${API_URL}/user/${username}/feed`);
  }
  static logOut(user){
    AsyncStorage.removeItem('@Trail:user');
  }
  static followUser(user, username){
    fetch(`${API_URL}/users/${username}/follow`, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json'
      }
    });
  }
  static createPost(user, text, longitude, latitude){
    fetch(`${API_URL}/posts/new`, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json'
      },
      user: user,
      body: {
        text: text,
        location: {
          longitude: longitude,
          latitude: latitude
        }
      }
    });
  }
  static likePost(user, id){
    fetch(`${API_URL}/posts/${id}/like`, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json'
      },
      user: user,
      params: {
        id: id
      }
    });
  }
  static unlikePost(user, id){
    fetch(`${API_URL}/posts/${id}/unlike`, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json'
      },
      user: user
    });
  }
  static getComments(id){
    fetch(`${API_URL}/posts/${id}/comments`, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json'
      }
    });
  }
}
```

I expected the code to work if I call it like this is any component:

```
async login(){
  const { username, password } = this.state;
  await Backend.logIn(username, password)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJSON) => AsyncStorage.setItem('@Trail:user', 
        JSON.stringify(responseJSON.user)));
    () => navigate('Home');
}
```

But instead, it throws a Promise rejection error. Is there anything I'm missing?
UPDATE: kindly look at the image below for the error:

[image: Error code for the fetch.]

Comment: What is the actual error you're getting? Stacktrace?

Comment: By the way, you're probably getting this error, because your `Backend` class static methods aren't actually returning the `Promises`, so `await` is throwing an Exception

Comment: @AlexandreWiechersVaz looks like they do from the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please try returning the fetch (so you can actually catch the Promise afterwards) like so:

```
 static logIn(username, password){
    return fetch(`${API_URL}/users/login`, {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json'
          },
          body: {
            username: username,
            password: password
          }
    });
}
```